# Stop jQuery loading on hover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a jQuery script that loads a PHP file containing a table. Is it possible to pause the table loading on hover? Also is it possible to set the interval to load the file instantly when the page is first loaded and then every 3 seconds after that?

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#results2').load('includes/chatlog.php');
        }, 3000); // refresh rate in milliseconds.
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: probably on hover you will have to `clearInterval`.and on hover out again `setInterval`

Answer (score 1):

To pause the timer when the `table` element is hovered you can use `clearInterval()`. You would then need to start the interval again when the mouse leaves the `table`. Also, to instantly request the data on page load you could extract the `load()` call to its own function which is executed immediately. Try this:

```
function getData() {
    $('#results2').load('includes/chatlog.php');
}

var timer;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    timer = setInterval(getData, 3000); // refresh every 3 seconds
    getData(); // get data on load

    $('#results2').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            clearInterval(timer);
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            timer = setInterval(getData, 3000);
        }
    });
});
```